# What is LCD bias voltage and where do I have to connect it?

Tags: lcd, voltage-level, electronics

I noticed that I have VB0+, VB0-, VB1+ and VB1- pins on my LCD. In the datasheet it says they are for the "LCD Bias Voltage". I have never heard about that. So what is it? Where do I have to connect it?

Here is the datasheet of the LCD: http://www.buydisplay.com/download/manual/ERC12864-655_Series_Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the interfacing document kindly provided on the same page as that datasheet:

- http://www.buydisplay.com/download/interfacing/ERC12864-655_Interfacing.pdf

It shows plainly that you need to connect 2.2µF capacitors between the + and - of each pair of pins.